# how to change the level of expand column in jqgrid dynamically?

Tags: jqgrid

I'm using jqgrid tree grid with the following configuration

```
colModel  :  
        [
            {
                name:'id',width :  30, editable : false, align:"right",sortable : false, hidden :  true, key :  true, hidedlg:true
            },
            {
                name:'no',width : 50, editable : false, align:"left", sortable : true,sorttype:"text"
            }
            },
            {
                name:'name', width : 300, editable : true, sortable : true, sorttype:"text"
            }
       ],

treeGridModel:'adjacency',
ExpandColumn:'name'
treeGrid: true,
cellEdit: true,
sortable: true,
```

From the above configuration,name is  my expand field,I'm passing level based on some hierarchy from server as json data.The user may wish to change the hierarchy on runtime.So I should change the level and indentation of the name field.I could set the level using "setCell" method but indentation is not updated,how to change the indentation?Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting of new value for the `level` is not so easy. Simple usage of `setCell` will not work. Let us you know the `rowid` you want to change `level` to `newLevel` value. I think the code should be about the following:

```js
var $iconDiv, iCol,
    $tr = $('#' + $.jgrid.jqID(rowid)),  //get the tree row
    rowData = $myGrid.jqGrid('getLocalRow', rowid),
    $grid = $("#list"), // grid
    getColumnIndexByName = function (myGrid, columnName) {
        var cm = myGrid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'colModel'), i,
            l = cm.length;

        for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            if (cm[i].name === columnName) {
                return i; // return the index
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }; // get local row data

// update level in the local jqGrid data
rowData.level = newLevel;

// update the position of the icon
$iconDiv = $tr.find("div.tree-wrap");
$iconDiv.width((newLevel + 1) * 18); // 18px per level
$iconDiv.children("div.treeclick:first").css("left", (newLevel * 18) + 'px');

// update the value in the hidden level column
iCol = getColumnIndexByName.call($grid, "level");
$tr.children('td:eq(' + iCol + ')').text(newLevel);
```

Comment: Can I use setTreeNode(iRow,level)?

Comment: @pavi: I'm not sure, but I think you can't. To be sure one have to examine the full code of `setTreeNode` and debug it. Inside of `setTreeNode(i, len)` will be modified the rows from the row with the row index `i` till the row with the row index `len`. If I understand you correct you want to adjust the level of **only one** row with the index `iRow`. So `setTreeNode(iRow,level)` will do not want you need.

Comment: No I have to adjust the whole tree according to the hierarchy.I used setTreeNode and one thing I couldn't understand is that How many indentations the method does once? because for me it's indenting twice.

Comment: @pavi: You should describe more exactly what you need. The current text of your question like "The user may wish to change the hierarchy on runtime" is too unclear.

Comment: "The user may wish to change the hierarchy on runtime" means that the user can left indent and right indent the name,for this I gave buttons. Where can I find the documentation for setTreeNode?Can you please give me some link which has the documentation.

Comment: @pavi: The method `setTreeNode` is not documented and I suppose it was introduced for internal purpose only.